# How to stop IntelliSense indenting if statements?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, formatting

My problem is that when I hit enter at the end of an `if` statement in Visual Studio it drops the statement to the next line. Eg,

I type:

```
if (X == Y) return (Z);
```

Visual Studio reflects:

```
if (X == Y)
   return (Z);
```

How do I stop Visual Studio from doing this and leave my `if` statements as I want them?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue (VS 2022 with default settings). Can you reproduce the issue in a new, empty C# project? Is it possible that the project you are using has custom [.editorconfig rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/code-style-rule-options)? Do you have some add-ins (Resharper?) that influence code formatting?

Comment: Why have some of the comments been removed.

Comment: I don't know (I'm not a moderator), but, in general, comments on StackOverflow are meant to be "temporary feedback to suggest improvements to a question or answer". They can be removed any time both by the author and by moderators. Common reasons to remove them would be that they are no longer needed (question or answer has been updated) or that they are off-topic (like this comment from me you are reading right now).

Comment: @Heinzi That's unfortunate. The comments are often where the most learning comes from. I just wish people or more likely Bots would leave them alone. See how long this comment last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check your new lines options in [the appropriate options section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/options-text-editor-csharp-formatting?view=vs-2022) (Style > Formatting > New Lines)